# Detecting HTTP 204 status of submitted form

Tags: javascript, http, forms

Is there a way to have a JavaScript event or check see if a submitted form got as response status HTTP 204?

Comment: example.com is reserved for examples.

Comment: (old comment removed) @Ates Goral: you're right... I know example.com. I wanted to state it's not on the same domain (no XHR). So example now: <html><body><form action="remote.example.com/post" method="post"><input type="file" name="file"><input type="submit"></form><script>/* wat? */</body></html> On a page that isn't on example.com.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: If it's a regular `<form>` submit, no.

You can only detect the response code if you use XHR.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible if not Ajax form submit. In this case logic needs to be handeled on the server and redirect to appropriate page.